# Show/Hide Tab Arrows to Navigate Additional Tabs on Overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right now, I have a tab structure that looks like the following:
[image: tabs-no-wrap]

As you can see, when the tabs reach the end of the line they wrap to the next line. I know how to hide the additional tabs; however, I want to introduce an arrow system to navigate to the additional tabs when the tabs overflow. Something that looks like below depending on the screen resolution:
[image: tabs]

I only want to have the arrows appear if there are additional tabs that are being hidden, this leads me to my question: How do I detect when the tabs wrap and insert the arrows?

I need this to work with responsive layouts.

Here is the code I am using to create the tabs (note: it includes hard-coded list items for the arrows):

```
<ul id="tabs" class="tab-links">
    <li class=""><a href="#tables">Tables &amp; Views</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#erd-tab" onclick="getERD()">ERD</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#left" class="gray-bg query-tab"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a class="query-tab" href="#query1">Query 1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query2" class="query-tab">Query 2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query3" class="query-tab">Query 3</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query4" class="query-tab">Query 4</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query5" class="query-tab">Query 5</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query6" class="query-tab">Query 6</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query7" class="query-tab">Query 7</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query8" class="query-tab">Query 8</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query9" class="query-tab">Query 9</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#right" class="gray-bg query-tab"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a></li>
    <!-- Hidden Tabs -->
    <li class=""><a href="#query10" class="query-tab">Query 10</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query11" class="query-tab">Query 11</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#query12" class="query-tab">Query 12</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You might consider using horizontal scrolling instead of arrow buttons. For mobile devices, I think it would be difficult to hit such a tiny arrow button. If you insist on doing it with arrows, you can measure the width of all the buttons by using .offsetWidth of the containing element. This will only work if the container is `display:table;` or width is set to exactly encapsulate the children elements. The other option is looping through all children and adding .offsetWidth of all the buttons. From there, the specifics of which buttons will fit can be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer requested:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', initTabs);

function initTabs() {
  var listContainer = document.getElementById('tabs');
  var buttonWidthCounter = 0;
  var totalContainerWidth = listContainer.offsetWidth;
  for (var i = 0; i < listContainer.children.length; i++) {
    if (buttonWidthCounter + listContainer.children[i].offsetWidth > totalContainerWidth) {
      //button overflow...add tab buttons
      console.log('there is overflow...add tab arrow buttons...');
    }
    buttonWidthCounter += listContainer.children[i].offsetWidth;

  }
}
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tabs" class="tab-links">
  <li class=""><a href="#tables">Tables &amp; Views</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#erd-tab" onclick="getERD()">ERD</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#left" class="gray-bg query-tab"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a class="query-tab" href="#query1">Query 1</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query2" class="query-tab">Query 2</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query3" class="query-tab">Query 3</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query4" class="query-tab">Query 4</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query5" class="query-tab">Query 5</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query6" class="query-tab">Query 6</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query7" class="query-tab">Query 7</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query8" class="query-tab">Query 8</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query9" class="query-tab">Query 9</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#right" class="gray-bg query-tab"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a></li>
  <!-- Hidden Tabs -->
  <li class=""><a href="#query10" class="query-tab">Query 10</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query11" class="query-tab">Query 11</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query12" class="query-tab">Query 12</a></li>
</ul>
```

The answer I suggest:

Scrollbars are much easier to implement and are arguably better.

```css
li{
display:inline-block;
}

ul{
white-space:nowrap;
}

html,body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#container{
width:100vw;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<ul id="tabs" class="tab-links">
  <li class=""><a href="#tables">Tables &amp; Views</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#erd-tab" onclick="getERD()">ERD</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#left" class="gray-bg query-tab"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a class="query-tab" href="#query1">Query 1</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query2" class="query-tab">Query 2</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query3" class="query-tab">Query 3</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query4" class="query-tab">Query 4</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query5" class="query-tab">Query 5</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query6" class="query-tab">Query 6</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query7" class="query-tab">Query 7</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query8" class="query-tab">Query 8</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query9" class="query-tab">Query 9</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#right" class="gray-bg query-tab"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a></li>
  <!-- Hidden Tabs -->
  <li class=""><a href="#query10" class="query-tab">Query 10</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query11" class="query-tab">Query 11</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#query12" class="query-tab">Query 12</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it out and see how it works! I should add that although scrollbars would work, they would hurt the look of the site because the tabs are flush with the div that contains the content. The scrollbar would then get in the way.

Comment: @Dustin with hiding tabs, you'll also have to calculate how many to hide and account for possible browser window resizes. I.e. someone resizes the browser window.

Comment: Yep. I am in the process of doing that. This works. Thank you so much!